SSIS scheduled job on SQL Server Agent has error
I am running an SSIS package using SQL Server Agent, logging in using the "sa" account (system admin).
The SSIS package runs by itself with no issues.
However, when I schedule it using the SQL Server Agent as a job, it does not run. When I am setting up the scheduled job, the credentials allow me to find the SSIS package from the server.
Would anyone know why? I've read a few posts, but it seems like no one has encountered the exact issue before.
Thanks for your help.
Disclaimer: This is from an air-gapped system, and the error below is from a photo (text recognition), and may have typo.
Executed as user: NT Service \SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utilty Version 16.0.1000.6 for 64-bit Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
xxxxxx Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB**
Started: 11:30:00 AM Error: 2024-09-04 11:30:06.09 Code: 0xC0202009
Source: Data 360
Description: "Login failed for user "SA'". End Error Error: 2024-09-04 11:30:06.09
Description: SSIS Eror Code DTS_ E OLEDBERROR, An OLE DB error has occurred, Eror code: 0x800404D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Hresurce: 30040E40
Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - Query [20]
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The
11:30:06.09 Code: 0xC0047017
Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS. Pipeline
Description: Source - Query failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Description: One or more component failed validation. End Eror Error: 2024-09-04 11:30:06.09
End Error Error: 2024-09-04 11:30:06.09
Code: 0xC0024107
Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
Source: Data Flow Task
Started: 11:30:00 AM Finished: 11:30:06 AM Elapsed: 5.203 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed.
Description: There were errors during task validation. End Error DExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).


"Login failed for user "SA'" you need to get the true authentication error from the SQL Server logs. If you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include it (though, why are you using the sa account for this?)

Does the actual error message say "Login failed for user "SA'" (with the messed up quotes), or is that just OCR errors?

Aside... Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 has been deprecated since SQL Server 2012 days and Microsoft (finally) no longer ships it as of SQL Server 2022. If you're targeting modern SQL Server instances you may have more luck with an up to date OLEDB Driver for SQL Server.

@ThomA it is an air-gapped system that I don't administer, just being asked to assist and given sa credentials. Aside from the security concern, does SSIS and sql server agent not work with SA account?

@AlwaysLearning it is OCR error. And I acknowledge that much of the system is outdated -- it is not administered by me.

And yet you have the sa credentials? What? That makes no sense. I suspect that the credentials you've been given are wrong. I suggest you talk to whomever the DBA is, get them to create you an account with the minimal needed permissions and then try that. Then, if the connection fails, talk to them; we can't support you here as this is a help desk issue.

@ThomA thanks. The credentials work with the SSIS package - the SSIS package works when run by itself. The error ocurrs when the SSIS package (sql query, followed by exporting to a flat file in C drive) is run by the SQL server agent as a scheduled job. Since you mention this is a helpdesk issue, let me check with the administrator again.

Supplementing ThomA's suggestion of checking the SQL Server logs, as in: look for Error 18456 Login failure messages, take note of their State number(s) and compare them against those listed at MSSQLSERVER_18456. This should give you more clues about why the login fails (it might be more than just the username or password being wrong).

Also, in the SSIS job step properties, do you have the "Use 32 bit runtime" checkbox near the bottom of the page checked? If it's unchecked possibly your system is missing 64 bit versions of required drivers or dependencies.
